# Using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to run web/load testing with SSL error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, load-testing, webtest

I have a contractor who created and uploaded test to VSTS but now when we run them we get:

```
The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

[Screen cap of errors](https://www.screencast.com/t/Z39fJIF0u)

How is this fixed? I am new to VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your certificate valid? This error most often comes from an invalid or development certificate, or from a certificate supplying a different TLS version to the one the client is expecting.

According to [this answer on Software QA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/22490), you can usually work around this by modifying the `ServicePointManager` in a pre-test handler plugin that you include with your code.

Please read the comments in this example from [the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e639498b-3e3b-4c47-8a38-b910a8be70fc/ssl-in-webtests-vsts-2008-and-2010?forum=vstswebtest) - you should modify the call-back function to perform some validation on the certificate to ensure it is the environment you are expecting.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;


namespace ExperimentalTesting
{
  [Description("This plugin will force the underlying System.Net ServicePointManager to negotiate downlevel SSLv3 instead of TLS. WARNING: The servers X509 Certificate will be ignored as part of this process, so verify that you are testing the correct system.")]
  public class SSLv3ForcedPlugin : WebTestPlugin
  {
    [Description("Enable or Disable the plugin functionality")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Enabled {get;set;}

    public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
      base.PreWebTest(sender, e);

      // We're using SSL3 here and not TLS. Update as required.
      // Without this line, nothing works.
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

      // Wire up the callback so we can override behaviour and force it to
      // accept the certificate
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
                                             RemoteCertificateValidationCB;

      // Log the changes to the service point manager
      e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult(this.ToString() + " has made the following modification-> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol set to use SSLv3 in WebTest Plugin.");
    }

    public static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCB(Object sender, 
                                                     X509Certificate certificate,
                                                     X509Chain chain,
                                                     SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      // Validate the certificate issuer here 
      // (at least check the O, L, C values, better yet the signature).
      // Returning true will accept any certificate
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

This will then need to be added to your Web Test as per the [MSDN documentation on creating Web Test Plugins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191.aspx).

You will need to follow a similar process to create a Load Test plug-in (inheriting instead from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.ILoadTestPlugin) and follow the [MSDN documentation on creating Load Test Plugins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153.aspx).

Comment: If your load/web test were recorded do I need to start from scratch? I don't see any code files.

Comment: @cdub It is webtest plug-in, so you need to create a plug-in and use it to your web test. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: After that do I just run it? I guess I need to learn how to get it into the cloud too.

Comment: I followed your above link but running the test still produced this https://www.screencast.com/t/AZUWTf0BSNvM

Comment: @cdub apologies, it's been a long time since I've used VSTS, but I've come up against that error before in general .net contexts. Starian Chen's link may help.

Comment: You'll probably need the original project from the contractor to add the plugin to it.

Comment: Make sure you follow **all** of the instructions in the link that @starianchen-MSFT provided. Missing any of them can mean the plugin is unusable.

Comment: I have the tests. Do I need to add the plugin anywhere other than as a reference? It was only added as a reference and I changed nothing else.

Comment: @cdub Check the steps from 19 to 23.

Comment: And how do I do it for a load test? I see this is for a web test plugin.

Comment: I got it added to the web test. Need to do a load test too.

Comment: @cdub - There's a link at the top of the Web Test page that says "You can also create Load Test plugins": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153.aspx