# Using VS Enterprise to run load tests on a site behind a firewall

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, load-testing

I have visual stuido enterprise 2015 and am using VSTS to load test staaging and production sites which are on the internet. I believe the only way to load test was using VSTS in the cloud. This prevents me for load testing a dev site behind a firewall. Is there a way to do this? I finally got my visual studio load testing based on another ticket here:
[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822386/using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-to-run-web-load-testing-with-ssl-error/47822598?noredirect=1#comment82620006_47822598)

Comment: If it's a staging site you're load testing, how about disabling the firewall and only allowing access from your IP Address? If it's a production site you're testing, well, don't do that. Bad idea.

Comment: See *"Can I run cloud-based load tests on any app, even behind a firewall?"* at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/reference-qa

Comment: Do you solve the issue with Clemens's solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it when creating your own load agents with fixed up address and whitelist these. I remember that you could send a request to the VSTS team with your account and they would give you an ip address for the load test. 
See this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/03/09/load-testing-applications-behind-firewall-using-trusted-ip/

And https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/23/testing-privateintranet-applications-using-cloud-based-load-testing/