# Can a VSTS Cloud Load Test be configured to run a setup script before the test?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, load-testing

Prior to the test, I'd like to have a pre-test setup script make an API call to obtain a current auth token and then have the request headers in the load test web scenario refer to this token. To clarify what's meant by "prior to the test": Each run of a test might make hundreds of API calls using the exact same parameters: URL, headers, etc. I want the pre-test script to run before the test to populate a header value, but I don't need it to run before each of the API calls made during that test.

Comment: How about using load test plugin? Related articles: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/12/08/creating-load-test-plugins-for-cloud-based-load-test/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822386/using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-to-run-web-load-testing-with-ssl-error

Comment: What does *"Prior to the test (not prior to each run)"* mean? How often do want the script to run (compared to test runs, to days, to test iterations, etc)? Please [edit] the question to explain more clearly what you want. You have the makings of an interesting question but there is no enough detail to understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks @starianchen-MSFT - I'm trying to use the VSTS web UI and haven't seen a way that it can support load test plugins

Comment: @MarkSoper I am afraid that you can't do it through web UI.